# Cannot connect to MySQL via Python using pyodbc and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, odbc, pyodbc

I have been struggling to connect to a mysql db using pyodbc. The problem is, I can't find the appropriate syntax anywhere. I have seen different syntax on the internet, including stackoverflow, but they are not working for me.
First of all, what should I pass to the "DRIVER" param for the connection. Is it the odbc driver available in the system?
What is the difference between using UID and Pass v/s Trusted connection?
Here is the code I am using now. Please help.

```
    def createconnection(host, port, db, uid, pwd):
        '''
        To create a mysql connection 
        '''
        try:
            odbcpath = r'C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe'
            params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe};"
                                             f"SERVER={host,port};"
                                             f"DATABASE={db};"
                                             "Trusted_connection=yes")
            # db_engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pyodbc://{host}/{db}?driver={odbcpath}? 
              Trusted_Connection=yes')
            db_engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}")
            self.connection = db_engine.connect()
        except:
            print('Error while creating the db engine and connection')
            raise
```

This code is giving the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)
```

If possible please explain what ODBC/DSN is and how is connection using DSN different from connection using UID and PWD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL, you first need to decide whether you really do want to use ODBC. For SQLAlchemy the preferred MySQL DBAPI layer is [mysqlclient](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb).

In order to use ODBC successfully on Windows you need an ODBC driver *for your specific database*. ODBC drivers are not interchangeable.

For MySQL, the ODBC driver is [MySQL Connector/ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/). You install it like any other Windows program. Once installed it appears in your ODBC Administrator

[image: ODBC Administrator]

and you would use `DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver` or `DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver` depending on your needs. See the [Unicode notes in the pyodbc wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode#mysql-and-postgresql) for details.

`Trusted_Connection=yes` is a connection string parameter for Microsoft SQL Server ODBC drivers and is not applicable to MySQL ODBC.